# Syntax for retrieving Array in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode

Apologies if this is a simple question, but I'm looking for the right syntax to retrieve an array from my structure file in Swift. The function below does not work for me.

```
func fetchArray(completion: @escaping ([Array])-> ()) {

     ...code

     let finalArray = Array(someList) 

     completion(self.finalArray)
}
```

Comment: Add the code of your structure. What is `someList` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`finalArray` and `self.finalArray` are two different objects, the former is a local variable, the latter is a property.

You have to write

```
completion(finalArray)
```

to avoid the confusion use another name

```
let localArray = Array(someList) 
completion(localArray)
```

Another issue is `[Array]` which is an array in an array, pass the actual static type of the array for example

```
func fetchArray(completion: @escaping ([String])-> ()) {
```